# Sass: Why can't I have a comment after an @import (on the same line)?

Tags: css, sass

```
@import "foo" // Bar
```

...results in `Invalid CSS after ""foo" ": expected media query list, was "// Bar"`. Why?

Thanks for explanation.

Comment: This isn't a problem someone can solve, you need to talk to the developer to get an answer.

Comment: Have you tried `/* ... */` style comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The CSS spec defines the [@import rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css-cascade-3-20130730/#at-import) as

   ```
   <import-rule> = @import [ <url> | <string> ] <media-query-list>? ;
   ```

   which means `@import` followed by a string or a url followed by an optional list of media types
2. In [Sass syntax](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html#comments), comments must be on their own line

   > Like everything else in the indented syntax, comments are line-based.
   >   This means that they don’t work the same way as in SCSS. They must
   >   take up an entire line, and they also encompass all text nested
   >   beneath them.

The parser expects a list of media types, finds a comment mixed with content and chokes on it.

You will have to split the comment and the content in Sass syntax:

```
 // Bar
 @import "foo"
```

Comment: This is a bit annoying, but okay, we'll have to accept it. :)

Answer (score -2):

> you can try

```
@import "foo"; // Bar
```

> actually you are missing semi-colon after your variable declaration.

Comment: Your code is the same as the question. Also why are you blockquoting your sentences?